# dsBytes, dwFlags parameters of WSARecv

Tags: c++, sockets, winapi, visual-c++

Can I safely pass local variables `DWORD dsBytes, dwFlags = 0` into async [WSARecv](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741688%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) call from previous completion routine or they can go out of scope before WSARecv ends its using?
MSDN:

> If this function is completed in an overlapped manner, it is the
>   Winsock service provider's responsibility to capture the WSABUF
>   structures before returning from this call. This enables applications
>   to build stack-based WSABUF arrays pointed to by the lpBuffers
>   parameter.

But there is nothing like this about dsBytes and dwFlags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use local variables. The flags aren't used once the WSARecv() call returns, and the byte count is sent as a parameter to the completion routine or retrieved by calling [`WSAGetOverlappedResult()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741582%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).